# Android Spinner populate using ArrayList

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner, the drop down list has the correct options from my WebService, but when I selected one option, this have not shown in the Spinner field.

My ArrayAdapter definition...

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                             (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,catTorneo);
```

catTorneo has the options, it's definition as ArrayList

If I change The ArrayAdapter with List object, the Spinner correct fine.

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Android");
                list.add("Java");
                list.add("Spinner Data");
                list.add("Spinner Adapter");
                list.add("Spinner Example");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                             (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
```

catTorneo Definition

```
ArrayList<String> catTorneo ;
```

In onTaskComplete method I populate catTorneo as..

```
try {
                ljsonArray = ljsonObject.getJSONArray(tag);
                for (int i = 0; i < ljsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    ljsonObject = ljsonArray.getJSONObject(i);                  
                    // Llena el spinner con el nombre de c/u de los nombres de torneos
                    String ls = ljsonObject.optString("tor_nombre");
                    catTorneo.add(ljsonObject.optString("tor_nombre"));

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

What happened?, why with  ArrayList object doesn't work fine and with List object work fine.

Comment: show the declaration and definition for `catTorneo`

Comment: Oks, up put declaration and definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your changes to the `ArrayList` has not been notified to the spinner.

What i would do?

In `onTaskComplete` method

```
 ljsonArray = ljsonObject.getJSONArray(tag);
 for (int i = 0; i < ljsonArray.length(); i++) {
         ljsonObject = ljsonArray.getJSONObject(i);                  
         // Llena el spinner con el nombre de c/u de los nombres de torneos
         String ls = ljsonObject.optString("tor_nombre");            
         catTorneo.add(ljsonObject.optString("tor_nombre"));
 }
 //add this line
 dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //tells the spinner that data has changed
 //put a toast here so that ull know when the data has be added to it :)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your list is full of String why dont you make things simpler?

You can use this

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.yourSpinner'sId);
String[] myItems = {"Android", "Java", "Spinner Data", "Spinner Adapter", "Spinner Example"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item_1, myItems);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If you have more than a string then you gonna have to make your own adapter